# The meaning of colon (:), can be... what? Similary to equal(=)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Excluding `":this()"` and within `"if()"` statements, what can possible mean the `":"` operator?

In the next example, sort of irrelevant, I want to find, within a collection of `<a href>` links, either of 2 things:

- all items that don't have '.ib-content' class;
- the first `<span>` inside all `<a href>` links found that meets the criteria having "objToWhom_Id" (func passed var) on is text.

So, for instance, on this code:

```
init_stuff = function(objToWhom_Id) { 
   $ibItems        = $ibWrapper.find('div.ib-main > a');
   $ibImgItems     = $ibItems.not('.ib-content');

   if(objToWhom_Id == "allHTMLitems"){
       imgItemsCount = $ibImgItems.length;
   }else{
       ++imgItemsCount;
       //Here we are; notice the ":"
       $ibImgItems : $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(objToWhom_Id)');
       //
       console.log($ibImgItems.html();
   }
}
```

everything works fine (the 'init_stuff()' function is Deferred, btw)...

But if we change the above line to:

```
       $ibImgItems = $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(objToWhom_Id)');
```

which should be the reasonable thing, doesn't work anymore... :-P

Any help?

---

### EDITED

To test ":" works, you can add (as actually the main thing has!) an event to the pointed object, inside `init_stuff()` right at the end:

```
$ibImgItems.bind('click.ibTemplate', function(clik_$ibImgItem) {
    clik_$ibImgItem.preventDefault();
    openItem($(this));
    return false;
});
```

It works, @Hans! ;-)

Comment: In your example, `$ibImgItems :` is a label, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Take a look at the answer posted below by @Hans, if this doesnt solve your problems. Please post an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or something similar) to showcase your problem, people here at SO love jsFiddles. I mean literally, we love them.

Comment: @Pedro You might be interested in Stack Overflow in your native language, it was recently launched: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Tx @Rob W! In the first experienced times, I'd stick with english. After all, the native language languages! ;-) Cheers!

Comment: Tx @Rob W!!! I think you have the RIGHT answer! I didn't knew it at all! Tx.
So... $ibImgItems is like pointing to `<a href>` which has the condition stated... but, realy represents the `<a href>` object. Is that it? Only so can explain the correct functioning.

Comment: Any other way of coding it (the link you stated says «Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid using labels and, depending on the cases,»)?

How to find the `<a href>` wanted and assign $ibImgItems to it?

Comment: Tx @Hans: `$ibImgItems = $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(' + objToWhom_Id + ')').closest('a')` gets the same result and doesn't need the use of LABELs anymore. Tx you guys! Great! Another lesson today (labeling...!)

Answer (score 2):

The `:`-operator should not do anything here, except make sure that the line fails. I have a feeling that your line doesn't work as is, and starts working when you replace the `:` with an `=`-operator.

There seems to be another mistake:

`$ibImgItems = $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(objToWhom_Id)');`

Change this to:

`$ibImgItems = $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(' + objToWhom_Id + ')');`

Does that by any chance solve the problem?

Edit: to answer your question a bit more: one case where `:` equals `=` is in object literal syntax:

```
var object = { property: value, someOtherProperty: someOtherValue };
```

Comment: also a missing parenthesis at the end of the console.log

Comment: Hi @Hans! Tx for quick answer!
Exactly! The passed var is already a string (an ID)...
Great! Tx!
But... how cames it was working?
Another issue: now we can really console.log the html of each found `<span>`!
But, using ":" what I get is the completely inside `<a href>` structure HTML (which has a lot of `<div>`'s and `<span>`'s...

Strange... :-(

Comment: (I still don't have 15 of reputation to "thumbs up". But thank you guys!)

Still.... any ideas what the ":" is working over there?

Comment: I think it wasn't really working, but earlier in your code you set `$ibImgItems = $ibItems.not('.ib-content');` That is probably what you were seeing all the time when you had the colon instead of the equal sign. This is probably also why you see that issue you mentioned in the comments, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks @leszek.hanusz! That was actualy a transcribe mistake; at the machine the code has the final')'.
Yeap @Hans! Thanks again!

So... can it be the same as "=", the colon sign?
Now that all "bad" writing is corrected, changing to one, or another operator, it works!
Although, as explained by Hans, you get different console.log, they all... work!
So..? The same?... ;-) I really would like to assertively know that.

Comment: Actually the correct statement is with ":", because is selecting the `<a href>`tag. And (in outter code) thats the object we want to bind a'click' event. The statement with "=" selects ONLY the  `<span>` inside the `<a href>`. Question is, so, still valid.

Comment: Pedro, you're still making the same mistake in your thought process: the line with the colon is NOT valid, you need the equal-operator for it to work as it syntactically should. However, the line looks for SPANS, and you now say you don't want spans, but you want the anchor tags around it. There is more than one way to do this, e.g. `$ibImgItems = $ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(' + objToWhom_Id + ')').closest('a');`. But the most important thing to understand here, if you use the colon, the line will not execute the way you expect it to.

Comment: Nopes, @Hans! See the @Rob answer! It's a LABEL! It's VALID and brings the correct value to the `$ibImgItems` var. Your code solution is ALSO correct (get the `<a href>` imediately closer to the `<span>` just found)! But... main thing, now I know what ":" means: a label! Tx to you all, guys!

Comment: You're right that it is a label, and in that sense it is valid, like you say. However, the line of code no longer works as you expect it to: the result of your query `$ibItems.find('span:first').filter(':contains(' + objToWhom_Id + ')');` will NOT be assigned to `$ibImgItems`. The query will be executed and then immediatly dropped from memory. So `$ibImgItems` will still have its previous value. So the code works syntactically, but it does not assign anything to the variable!

Comment: Nopes, @Hans. At all! Ive tryed it! It works. Inside teh function, `$ibImgItems` will have the `<a href>´ object consistently. I even can assign events to it! Try it...

Comment: I've edited the initial question, and add the click event, @Hans.

Answer (score 2):

The colon in JavaScript can be used as a ternary operator

```
TestExpression ? ValueIfTrue : ValueIfFalse
```

Or it could be used as a label

```
var i = 100, a = 100;
outerloop:
while(i > 0) {
  while(a > 0) {
   a++
   if(a>50) {
     break outerloop;
   }
  }
  i++
}
```

Or it can be used to assign key/value pairs

```
var MyObject = { keyName1: "value1", keyName2: "value2" }
```

Comment: Hi @Howard Renollet:
As i EXPLAINED on the post:
"Excluding ":this()" and within "if()" statements, what can possible mean the ":" operator?"

Comment: Sorry... just skipped the "Or it could be used as a label" part... ;-). Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Although not so "clean" as the one provided by @Hans, here is another way of avoiding "label", using another 'outer' "filter":

```
var $ibImgItems = $ibItems
                     .filter(function(){
                          return $(this).find('span:first').filter(':contains('+objToWhom_Id +')');
                     });
```

I think it goes better with the logical of "label", in order to replace it, in this very particulary case. Just a thought.

Thanks again for all contributions!